# Bind Vue Background image with spaces

Tags: css, .net, vue.js, model-view-controller, razor

I'm trying to set background image css property, when the image does not have spaces the image is rendered correctly, but when the image has spaces in the name, it is not rendered, because the information I bring from a database, it is difficult for me to rename all the images.

```
<div :style="{'min-height':'200px', 'background-image': 'url(/18edp/Content/img/empresas/' + e.Name + '.jpg)'}"></div>
```

When image's name is E.G. **imagename.jpg** the code is worked, but the image has a space E.G. **image name.jpg** the code is not worked.

Can you help me, please?

Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace whitespaces with '%20', in this case use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURIComponent)

```
<div :style="{'min-height':'200px', 'background-image': 'url(/18edp/Content/img/empresas/' + encodeURIComponent(e.Name) + '.jpg)'}"></div>
```